# Using Wordpress, it is possible to filter posts by sub-category on the main posts page?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

My my Wordpress 'post page', currently I have posts across a number of categories.  My posts page (driven by index.php) has a 'tabs' bar which allows the user to dynamically filter the posts they see by clicking on a category.

The tabs bar is generated by the following code:

```
<li><a <?php if(!($_GET['category'])) echo ' class="_active"'; ?>href="<?php echo get_permalink(get_option('page_for_posts')); ?>">Show All</a>
<?php $i = 1; foreach($categories as $category): ?>
<li><a<?php if(($_GET['category'] == $category->slug)) echo ' class="_active"'; ?> href="<?php echo get_permalink(get_option('page_for_posts')).'?category='.$category->slug; ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></a></li>
<?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

These are then styled as buttons, so I have a series of buttons like (Category 1) (Category 2) (Category 3) etc which when clicked on load the relevant posts below.

What I am trying to do now is where a post has two categories, I'd like these to be displayed in two tab bars.

So for example, I might have a tab bar that is (for example): Ford, Mercedes, BMW
And then a second tab bar which is: Black, Red, Yellow

So If I have a post that is categorised as Mercedes and Black, then this will show if I filter on either Mercedes or Black.

Almost like a two-tier category system?

Hope this makes sense?  Any advice appreciated.

EDIT:  Had a thought, could this work?

At the top of my index.php page I have the following variables:

```
$categories = get_categories(array('orderby' => 'name', 'exclude' => array(1)));
$category = ($_GET['category']) ? $_GET['category'] : '';
$wp_query->set('category_name', $category);
$wp_query->set('cat', '-1');
$wp_query->query($wp_query->query_vars);
```

So could I change this to have a $categoriesA and $categoriesB, where each excludes the relevant category IDs, and then publish two tab bars by duplicating the following but reference $categoriesA in the former and then $categoriesB in the latter?

```
<?php $i = 1; foreach($categories as $category): ?>
                                <li><a<?php if(($_GET['category'] == $category->slug)) echo ' class="_active"'; ?> href="<?php echo get_permalink(get_option('page_for_posts')).'?category='.$category->slug; ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></a></li>
                            <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
```

Will try this (currently don't have write access to index.php so will try when I can).

Comment: Its not good idea to use categories for both since they are not hierarchical. Also your code will require maintaining all the time when you add new brand or color.. Use different taxonomy for color or meta this will give you also the ability to make it adoptive or not and will be automated.

Comment: Thanks for this - can you explain how I would use different taxonomy? Thanks

Comment: Read about it here - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/ also you can use this tool for it - https://generatewp.com/taxonomy/